# Speed of light, comparison of two light waves travelling side by side

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, speed, observers

[image: diagram of my question]

okay so.here is setup of my question...say we have two observers A and A'..A is fixed to origin of coordinate axis x,y while A' is inside a hollow box (shown as rectangle MNRP) whose one side MN has been extended to N' to recieve light from A. we define two simultabeous events-
!. light is shot by A and A' towards the wall MN' and MN,
2. the box MNRP is given a velocity v (0<=v<=c), and the box travels parallel to x axis.
assumptions are as follow- both the lights travel parallel to x axis, the velocity given to box MNRP is instant (i mean no acceleration or effect of inertia..it instantly attains a velocity v)
so, my question is..which light will reach the wall MN (or MN') first?

Comment: see, if i replace any observer with myself and then observe the two light waves moving..what should i see? probably that both light waves are moving side by side and reach MN simultaneously...right? but then, wouldnt that mean that one light is moving slowly or that the other is moving faster than the other..?

Comment: if both of them reach simultaneouly, wouldnt that mean the light shot from outside is moving faster than  the one shot from the inside of the box?

Comment: try to visualise it..replace light with bullets and box with train...

Comment: yes, it is a part of box and is moving with velocity v

Comment: You have to use [Lorentz Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Boost_in_the_x-direction).

Comment: I suspect the answer involves the [relativity of simultaneity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity) and that  observations by A and A' will disagree about which beam of light was emitted at which times. This is a variation of the train-and-platform thought experiment.

Comment: let us say that both the observer were at rest and were not so far away from each other when they emitted the light, thus we can neglect relativity of simultaneity..and then the box MNRP was suddenly and instantly given a velocity v..